# php UDF function doesn't work from trigger SQlite database

Tags: php, sqlite, triggers, udf

I have UDF (user defined function) exec_script(), which create file on disc (win7).

I registered it:
    `$db = new SQlite3('name.db');`
    `$db->createfunction('exec_script','exec_script');`

If I call the udf in this way:
    `$db->querySingle('SELECT exec_script()');`

the function executed perfect.

But then I try to call it from the trigger, nothing happens. And I haven't message like this "no such function: exec_script()" too. It means that the function is call, but doesn't work.

SQlite trigger's code is
    `create trigger callfunc BEFORE UPDATE OF cases ON status`
    `FOR EACH ROW`
    `BEGIN`
    `SELECT exec_script();`
    `END`

How can I check the trigger?
Thanks

Comment: debugging: `var_dump(__FUNCTION__, __FILE__.__LINE__);` early in your `exec_script` function. I would also add it add the end of the function before the return statement if you have one.If you see the output from `var_dump` then you know the trigger is being called. I have tested that `var_dump` works fine in functions called from sqlite3 triggers.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I tried it. And it's founded that udf-function exec_script() doesn't call from the trigger. I call trigger from ajax, and initially I don't see the error: "no such function: exec_script()". Where I need to register the udf-function that the trigger see it? I register such way: $db = new SQlite3('name.db');
$db->createfunction('exec_script','exec_script'); may be It's another connection to the database?

Comment: Do you _always_ add the function to _every_ sqlite connection that you create. The function is not stored as part of the database. It needs to be added to every connection.

Comment: You also need to check that the trigger is actually being 'fired' on the update statement. To do that I would always insert a row into a separate 'logging' table from the trigger. That way you know the trigger is actually being run.

Comment: Ryan, many thanks! Trigger and function have been worked! I registered udf through PDO. Also I managed to come in udf-function through the breakpoint  (netbeans+xdebug) It's cool :)

Comment: I am pleased you got it working. :) And, yes, I  agree that being able call PHP from SQLite is a lot of fun! :)